# sparkR - subset values in list

Tags: r, apache-spark, filter, sparkr

How do I perform the following task for a spark data frame. 
In dplyr, I would do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 101:110)
df2 <- data.frame(r = 5:10, s = 205:210)
df3 <- df1 %>% filter(x %in% df2$r)
```

How do I perform the filter(x %in% df2$r) command for a sparkR dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had similar question and this seemed to work for filtering from a list:

```
df3 <- filter(df1, ("x in ('string1','string2','string3')"))
```

in your case, you might want to consider a join

```
df3 <- drop(join(df1, SparkR::distinct(SparkR::select(df2,'r')), df1$x==df2$r),'r')
```

(probably a bit too expensive though) ..

cheers,
anna

Comment: Problem is that I can't enumerate all x in ('string1', 'string2',...), There are 1000 such 'strings'

Answer (score 1):

Either don't convert the lookup to `SparkDataFrame`:

```
> df1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 101:110))
> df2 <- data.frame(r = 5:10, s = 205:210)
> filter(df1, df1$x %in% df2$r)
SparkDataFrame[x:int, y:int]
```

or convert both and `join`:

```
> df1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 101:110))
> df2 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(r = 5:10, s = 205:210))
> join(df1, df2, df1$x == df2$r, "leftsemi")
SparkDataFrame[x:int, y:int]
```

And don't use `dplyr` with SparkR. For `dplyr` compatible API use `sparklyr`.